# How to create a new list out of an existing list by removing duplicates and shifting values?

Tags: python, list

If I have the following list to start:

```
list1 = [(12, "AB"), (12, "AB"), (12, "CD"), (13, Null), (13, "DE"), (13, "DE")]
```

I want to turn it into the following list:

```
list2 = [(12, "AB", "CD"), (13, "DE", Null)]
```

Basically, if there is one or more text values with their associated keys, the second list has the key value first, then one the text value, then the other.  If there is no second string value, then the third value in the item if the second list is Null.

I've gone over and over this in my head and cannot figure out how to do it.  Using set() will cut down on exact duplicates, but there is going to have to be some sort of previous/next operation to compare the second values if the key values are the same.

The reason I am not using a dictionary is that the order of the key values has to stay the same (12, 13, etc.).

Comment: I'd rather used sorted dict  or external list of order [12,13,etc]

Comment: An [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) remembers the order keys are added.

Comment: Ok, so if we use an OrderedDict (thanks for pointing out that this exists), I still don't know how to create the new dict with the duplicate values removed and the values arranged as I need them to be.

Comment: Does the order of the strings matter - i.e. "AB" before "CD"?

Comment: To Jared:  the order does not matter, but if there is a null value it must be second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way would loop through `list1` multiple times, grabbing the relevant values each time. First time to grab all the keys. Then for each key, grab all the values ([repl.it](http://repl.it/J9K/1)):

```
Null = None
list1 = [(12, "AB"), (12, "AB"), (12, "CD"), (13, Null), (13, "DE"), (13, "DE")]

keys = []
for k,v in list1:
    if k not in keys:
        keys.append(k)
list2 = []
for k in keys:
    values = []
    for k2, v in list1:
        if k2 == k:
            if v not in values:
                values.append(v)
    list2.append([k] + values)

print(list2)
```

If you would like to improve the performance, I would use a dictionary as an intermediate so you don't have to traverse `list1` multiple times ([repl.it](http://repl.it/J9K/3)):

```
from collections import defaultdict 
Null = None
list1 = [(12, "AB"), (12, "AB"), (12, "CD"), (13, Null), (13, "DE"), (13, "DE")]

keys = []
for k,v in list1:
    if k not in keys:
        keys.append(k)

intermediate = defaultdict(list)
for k, v  in list1:
    if v not in intermediate[k]:
        intermediate[k].append(v)

list2 = []
for k in keys:
    list2.append([k] + intermediate[k])

print(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way i can see is the following:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict

>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> for (k, v) in [(12, "AB"), (12, "AB"), (12, "CD"), (13, None), (13, "DE"), (13, "DE")]:
...     if k not in d: d[k] = set()
...     d[k].add(v)

>>> d
OrderedDict([(12, {'AB', 'CD'}), (13, {'DE', None})])
```

or, if you want lists (which will also keep the value order) and don't mind being a little less efficient (because the `v not in ...` test has to scan the list):

```
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> for (k, v) in [(12, "AB"), (12, "AB"), (12, "CD"), (13, None), (13, "DE"), (13, "DE")]:
...     if k not in d: d[k] = []
...     if v not in d[k]: d[k].append(v)

>>> d
OrderedDict([(12, ['AB', 'CD']), (13, [None, 'DE'])])
```

and finally, you can convert that back to a list with:

```
>>> list(d.items())
[(12, ['AB', 'CD']), (13, [None, 'DE'])]
>>> [[k] + d[k] for k in d]
[[12, 'AB', 'CD'], [13, None, 'DE']]
>>> [(k,) + tuple(d[k]) for k in d]
[(12, 'AB', 'CD'), (13, None, 'DE')]
```

depending on exactly what format you want.

[sorry, earlier comments and reply had misunderstood the question.]

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

pairs = [(12, "AB"), (12, "AB"), (12, "CD"),
         (13, None), (13, "DE"), (13, "DE")]

result = defaultdict(set)
for k,v in pairs:
    result[k].add(v)

result = [(k,) + tuple(reversed(sorted(vs))) for k,vs in result.iteritems()]
```